# Find all non isomorphic trees, that have euler path.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

**Find all non isomrophic trees, that have euler path.**

So these trees should be:

o

o--o

o--o--o

o--0--o--0--...  to $\infty$

The situation:

o    
|   
o --0-- ... $\infty$ 
|
o    
|
o
Is not allowed because if we go right we won't be able to return back and go down the tree. What would You change in this way of thinking to make it more correct?

Comment: You are right. Since it is a tree there are no cycles. So if you can only use each edge once, you can't have a vertex of degree 3 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: A graph with an Euler path can have at most two vertices of odd degree. Let $T$ be a tree.

- What is the degree of every leaf of $T$?
- If a tree has more than one vertex, what is the smallest possible number of leaves it can have?
- What kinds of tree have the smallest possible number of leaves?

Answer (score 0):

*HINTS*

1) Because of tree , there are $n-1$ edges.

2) Because of Euler path , there are less or equal than 2 vertex with odd degree.

3) And we should remember about connectivity (degree of any vertex non zero).

Comment: And actually we should remember about handshaking lemma.